# Excel VBA - iterating through a list of entries to stack data from a table moving to multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to modify a previously written VBA script within an excel document. The aim of the script is basically to iterate through each column to produce on a single worksheet the relevant data to be parsed into a different program. It tries to clean the data (e.g. remove any -- etc.) and works fine.

For example it

[image: here is a link to an image of the input data]

```
Sub StackData()
    Dim SummaryTable As Range
    Dim OutRow As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long


    On Error Resume Next
    Set SummaryTable = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    SummaryTable.Select
    'Convert the range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For c = 2 To SummaryTable.Columns.Count
        Set OutWs = Sheets.Add
        OutWs.Name = Replace("out" & Left(SummaryTable.Cells(1, c), 5), " ", "")
        OutWs.Range("A1:C1") = Array("Id", "FundWgt", "Fund")
        OutRow = 2
            For r = 2 To SummaryTable.Rows.Count

                If IsNumeric(SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)) Then

                    OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 1) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, 1)
                    OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 2) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)
                    OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 3) = SummaryTable.Cells(1, c)
                    OutRow = OutRow + 1

                Else
                    'do nothing
                End If
            Next r
    Next c
End Sub
```

The output that comes out per sheet
[image: is here]

The issue has become is that we need to have two sets of data in the worksheet - a fund and its benchmark.

The data now looks
[image]

And I need the output to look like
[image]

I've tried a few things but I can't get it - I tried to make a summary worksheet where I declare the fund and benchmark here

[image: bench]

but can't figure out the next step

Apologies if I've missed this elsewhere. I'm a bit new to this so any help appreciated!

Comment: Where do different benchmarks go? Are they stacked on top of each other with repeating ids?

Comment: Benchmarks shouldn't be printed separately, only when outputted concurrently for funds

Comment: This is certainly doable, but your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: Also, it seems from your data that for each ID you have five funds and three benchmarks.  Should your final table, therefore, have 150 rows?  If not, how are you doing the selections?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, understand and will try next time to do so.

For what it's worth I was able to figure out how to do it (might not be most efficient but seems to get it done).

```
Sub StackData()
'   Before running this, make sure you have a summary table with column headers.
'   The output table will have three columns.
    Dim SummaryTable As Range, found As Range, b As Range
    Dim OutRow As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, bc As Long
    Dim OutWs As Worksheet
    Dim dataDate As String, benchmark As String

    Worksheets("Weights (Stocks)").Range("A7", "U7").Copy
    Worksheets("Weights (Stocks)").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Weights (Stocks)").Range("A10:B10") = Array("SEDOL", "Company Name")
    dataDate = Worksheets("Weights (Stocks)").Range("A6")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SummaryTable = Worksheets("Weights (Stocks)").Range("A10", Range("A10").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    SummaryTable.Select
    'Convert the range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For c = 3 To SummaryTable.Columns.Count - 4 '-4 reflects benchmarks
        Set OutWs = Sheets.Add
        OutWs.Name = Replace("o_" & Left(SummaryTable.Cells(1, c), 18) & Right(dataDate, 8), " ", "")
        OutWs.Range("A1:F1") = Array("SEDOL", "CompanyName", "Fund", "Weight", "Benchmark", "BmkWgt")
        OutRow = 2
        Set found = Sheets("Mandates").Columns("A").Cells.Find(what:=SummaryTable.Cells(1, c), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        benchmark = found.Offset(, 1).Value
        Set b = Sheets("Weights (Stocks)").Rows("10").Cells.Find(what:=benchmark, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        bc = b.Column
            For r = 2 To SummaryTable.Rows.Count
                    If IsNumeric(SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)) Or IsNumeric(SummaryTable.Cells(r, bc)) Then

                        OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 1) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, 1)
                        OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 2) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, 2)
                        OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 3) = SummaryTable.Cells(1, c)
                        OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 4) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)
                        OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 5) = SummaryTable.Cells(1, bc)
                        OutWs.Cells(OutRow, 6) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, bc)
                        OutRow = OutRow + 1
                    Else
                        'do nothing
                    End If
            Next r
    Next c
End Sub
```